# Configurar replicacion transaccional para un grupo de Always on SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, servidor

Tengo el siguiente entorno:

**Un servidor (A)** que tiene una publicación transaccional, este servidor no esta en el grupo de **`Always on`**

**Dos servidores (RT1 y RT2)** que están en un grupo de **`Always on`**

**Listener (RT)**

- RT1 es el primary
- RT2 es el secondary (Read Only)
- RT1 y RT2 estan sincronizados

El `RT(Listener)` tiene dos suscripciones, una para `RT1` y otra para `RT2`. Para el servidor que esta como **primary** (`RT1`) funciona muy bien ya que no es `Read Only`, pero para el **secondary** (`RT2`) no ocacionando que las `replicaciones` se pongan en espera hasta que el servidor deje de ser `read only` lo cual sucede con un `failover`, en ese momento las replicaciones comienzan a aparecer en el `RT2`, pero el `RT1` como ahora es **secondary** se vuelve `read only` y comienza a tener las replicaciones en espera.

¿Hay alguna otra manera de configurar para que `RT1` y `RT2` sean subscriptores del **servidor (A)** y que las replicaciones estén en ambos servidores?

Answer (score 0):

Me salio siguiendo este articulo
Se ejecutan en la base que se esta publicando y solo se puede hacer por codigo

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/replication-subscribers-and-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server